# WPF Control template: Property 'ContentStringFormat' was not found in type 'Control' error

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, themes

I found built-in themes in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\SystemThemes\Wpf folder; so I copied luna theme (luna.normalcolor.xaml) to my application folder, and
editing this theme to suit my needs. I also added reference to PresentationFramework.Luna.dll.
When I open luna.normalcolor.xaml file, VS2010 shows an error: Property 'ContentStringFormat' was not found in type 'Control', in the following lines:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}" 
           ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I checked that ContentPresenter class has ContentStringFormat property. So what causes
this error, and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this works correctly but I tried and got no error

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.ContentStringFormat}" />
</DataTemplate>
```